# Why does the Entity Framework ColumnBuilder take in a nullable bool to signify a nullable property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Referring to the `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders` `ColumnBuilder` class in Entity Framework 6, let's take for example the `Int` method.

If we are creating an EF migration we would add a column as following:

```
AddColumn("Table", "Column", c => c.Int());
```

In the last parameter to `AddColumn` we are passing in `c => c.Int()` where `c.Int()` invokes the `Int()` method on the ColumnBuilder class and returns a `ColumnModel`.

If we look at the definition of the `Int()` method we can see that the first parameter to this method is a `bool?` that will define whether the column in the DB is created as nullable or not.

The documentation says the paramater `nullable` is  a "Value indicating whether or not the column allows null values". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589880(v=vs.113).aspx. So I take it to mean that if it is `true` then the column will be made nullable, if it is `false` then not nullable.

The question is what happens if it is `null`?
Why does this `bool` attribute need to be nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that would depend on the `MigrationSqlGenerator` implementation.

For example, `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` adds `NOT NULL` to the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...` statement if `nullable == false`, but otherwise doesn't add anything. For `ALTER COLUMN`, `nullable == false` adds a `NOT` before `NULL` (which is in the generated statement, regardless).

So `nullable == null` would produce whatever the provider implementation has as its default.

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs.

Comment: That's interesting - so what you're saying is that my code to add a column `AddColumn("Table", "Column", c => c.Int());` could add a nullable column or even a non nullable column depending on the Sql Generator implementation. So maybe on SQL Server it could default to nullable but on Oracle perhaps it could default to not nullable. But if instead I used `c => c.Int(nullable: true)` then it the implementation should honor that and definitely make it nullable. Basically API was designed to have nullable as bool? to give the implementation freedom to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Per the SQL specification, a column added by `ADD COLUMN` is nullable by default, which I'm thinking most implementations would generally adhere to.